# how to create custom exception? and the condition is if the string length is greater than 100, just throw exception and catch?

Tags: java

```
package test2;

public class StringLargeException {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }    
}
```

Comment: please follow the package naming conventions by reading https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Answer (score 0):

Simple; put the following into some Test.java ... compile and run.

```
class MyException extends Exception {
   MyException(String message) { super(message); }
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
  throw new MyException("you didnt see this one coming");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. make a class A that extends From Exception class
2. make a constructor that you can pass a message to the class
3. then when you want to throw the exception  just type `throw new A("Message");`